# Traefik healthcheck not working. 'Bad gateway' returned instead of redirect to active servers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, bad-gateway, health-check

I'm learning Traefik basics, but can't get health checking to work. I have four servers, which are docker containers. The rotation is working well, when refreshing the localhost page, it shows a different server each time. Even launching multiples petitions with *Apache Benchmark* and monitoring them with *ctop*,shows a correct workload balance.  The matter came when I stop one of the servers. It is assumed that Traefik should detect the offline server and redirect to one of the active servers, but instead, when the rotation reachs the offline server, it shows a "Bad Gateway" message, so the health check is not working at all. I tried to replicate the documentation examples, but sure I'm missing something.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  traefik:
    image: asn/traefikv1
    build: traefikv1/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080" # Web GUI
    volumes:
      # Traefik static config file
     - ./traefikv1/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml  

  wwwserver:
    build: .
    image: phpwebapp
    ports:
      # Random external port for HTTP direct access 
      - "80"
      - "8080"
    scale: 4
    mem_limit: 50m
    mem_reservation: 25m
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mariadb 

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=notesdb
      - MYSQL_USER=usuario
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secreto
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

And this is my traefik.toml, where the health check is defined:

```
# Enable API and dashboard (:8080)
[api]

# Enable logs
[traefikLog]
[accessLog]

# Configure timeouts
[respondingTimeouts]

[file]

#Manual frontend/backend  configuration
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
    passHostHeader = true
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "wwwservers"
[backends]
  [backends.wwwservers]
      # Define www servers
      [backends.wwwservers.servers.server1]
          url = "http://pruebastraefik_wwwserver_1:80" 
      [backends.wwwservers.servers.server2]
          url = "http://pruebastraefik_wwwserver_2:80"    
      [backends.wwwservers.servers.server3]
          url = "http://pruebastraefik_wwwserver_3:80"
      [backends.wwwservers.servers.server4]
          url = "http://pruebastraefik_wwwserver_4:80"
      [backends.wwwservers.loadBalancer.healthCheck]
          path = "/health"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout = "3s"
          port= 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the labels for your services in the compose file.  Also note that version 2.4 is a so called experimental, I suggest you switch to 2.3.

In depth, I believe this is going on:  Most important you are missing the labels on you docker compose services. Also, the TOML file is working on the traefik service and not on the wwwserver which is the one you want to route. Tags such as "backends" and "frontends" should be included in the proper traefik tag, in my opinion traefik ignores them.

Also, it seems that the scale option would create additional containers to run the service on the same host (?).  It seems you are trying to have over control of you services defining what each scaled node is trying to serve.

I run several domains and services over a swarm cluster and traefik is my main point of entry and handles the networking of the cluster.  I write separate stack files with the tag "deploy" and a child-tag "labels" that includes all traefik rules for every service in the stack, very similar to the quickstart tutorial on the site, just with multiple compose file and the added deploy tag for docker swarm mode.  Good Luck